# Valid solution for Javascript sin() and cos()?

Tags: javascript, math

A client insists that sin(Math.PI) and cos(Math.PI / 2) should return zero, not something around 10^-16. He's not happy with the explanation that Math.sin() and Math.cos() are the way they are, not only in Javascript but in all other languages.

One thing I found, is that Math.sin() is insensitive to parameter changes smaller than 2e-16:

```
Math.sin(Math.PI)
1.2246063538223773e-16
Math.sin(Math.PI + 1e-16)
1.2246063538223773e-16
Math.sin(Math.PI + 2e-16)
1.2246063538223773e-16
Math.sin(Math.PI + 3e-16)
-3.216285744678249e-16
```

Since sin(x)~=x when sin(x) is near zero, it ocurred to me to cast sin(x) to zero when x is smaller than 2e-16.

Math.cos() is more precise, it is insensitive to changes up to 1.1e16 *(EDIT: it happens because base value is smaller: Math.PI/2)* so I would cast cos(x) to zero when it is smaller than 1e-16:

```
Math.cos(Math.PI / 2)
6.123031769111886e-17
Math.cos(Math.PI / 2 + 1e-16)
6.123031769111886e-17
Math.cos(Math.PI / 2 + 1.1e-16)
6.123031769111886e-17
Math.cos(Math.PI / 2 + 1.5e-16)
-1.6081428723391245e-16
```

Of course, such a cast would ruin the original good precision of sin(x) when x->0:

```
Math.sin(1e-99)
1e-99
Math.sin(1e-50)
1e-50
Math.sin(1e-40)
1e-40
Math.sin(1e-20)
1e-20
Math.sin(1e-10)
1e-10
Math.sin(1e-5)
0.000009999999999833334
```

But if the application were using such small angles, it should be using x directly, not sin(x), correct? Since sin(x) tends totally to x in this range.

Considering that the application has 10 digit of UI precision, do you feel my strategy is right?

Comment: "*A client insists*" get a better clients, preferably ones that have some understanding of floating point math. Does the client also demand that `.1 + .2 == .3`?

Comment: "Since sin(x)~=x when sin(x) is near zero" - wrong. It is - when x is near zero.

Comment: @epx See if http://mathjs.org/ of any help

Comment: @p.s.w.g all valid points but JavaScript aside logically wouldn't you expect `0.1 + 0.2 = 0.3` - now a customer unfamiliar with intricacies of JS floating point operations would think so too. And he doesn't care about what make the app tick - JS or leprechaun magic

Comment: @Igor sorry, I meant x mod 180 degrees, and there is the signal inversion, so they would be near in absolute terms.

Comment: Maybe the Taylor series would work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can decide on how close to zero you want to return zero-

```
Number.prototype.rounded= function(i){
    i= Math.pow(10, i || 15);
    // default
    return Math.round(this*i)/i;
}
Math.sin(Math.PI).rounded()
/*  returned value: (Number) 0 */

Math.PI.rounded(5)
/*  returned value: (Number) 3.14159 */
```

Comment: +1, Computers working with **numbers** like `π` can only ever **approximate**, i.e. `Math.PI` is not equal to `π`, so `sin(Math.PI)` is already different to `sin(π)`. This answer lets you have a much better idea of how big your computer error is in your calculations. If the client wants the solutions done symbolically, you can only really use identities and perhaps get away with integer addition, subtraction and multiplication.